# If field extension is finite, then smallest subfield equals smallest subring

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, extension-field

I have a doubt about the proof of the following result:

*Let $E/K$ be a finite field extension and $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be a finite subset of $E$. Denote $K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]$ the smallest subring of $E$ that contains $K$ and $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ and $K(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ the smallest subfield of $E$ that contains $K$ and $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$. Then*
$$K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]=K(e_1,\ldots,e_n).$$

The proof goes something like this:

*It suffices to show that $K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]$ contains every inverse of its elements. Let $a\in K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]$. We prove that the function $T_a:K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]\longrightarrow K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]$ given by
$T_a(b)=ab$ is surjective. Since $K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]$ can be thought as a vector space of finite dimension and $T_a$ is an injective endomorphism, it follows that $T_a$ is also surjective.*

My question is the following:

**Over which field can $K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]$ be thought as a vector space?**

I think $K$ is not the answer, since $T_a$ is not a $K$-linear mapping ($a$ may not be in $K$). Also, $K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]$ is not an $E$-vector space, since an element $K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]$ multiplied by an element in $E$ may not stay in $K[e_1,\ldots,e_n]$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $K$ is the answer and $T_a$ is $K$-linear.

Comment: @reuns, of course! I don't know why I was thinking that a $K$-linear map should be of the form $b\mapsto kb$, with $k\in K$.